# CloudSQL instances must be in the same project as the query connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create a connection to a Cloud SQL database in another GCP project in Big Query.  It will not allow me.  I am getting the message:

***CloudSQL instances must be in the same project as the query connection.***

How do I get around this?  Is my only option to copy the data from one project to another?

Comment: It can be explained because the resources are in different projects as the error message states. Please refer to the following links to know more about how to [Working with connections](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-connections).

Comment: The federated queries only work in the same project because when you create the External Data Source in Bigquery you use the Cloud SQL connection name (project_id:region:instance_name) which is valid only internally in a project, so there is no way to query the Cloud SQL database from Bigquery that is in another project unless you create a replica of your database in the second project where Bigquery lives. For this you can visit the following site  [Introduction to external datasources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources)

Comment: I don't see why BigQuery can't ask for permissions to decipher a connection name. Also, since the project_id is unique and within a project, a ClousSQL's instance name is unique in a region, the entire string is unique across the entire GCP ecosystem. How hard is to find the unique cloudsql instance Bigquery needs to talk to?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bad workaround. Create a view with the request to your Cloud SQL database in the same project as your Cloud SQL instance, and query this view from another project.

The problem (and why it's a bad workaround) is that you can't customize the Cloud SQL query. In fact, you should create a view for each table, and then create your query with all the views to achieve your joins and other SQL manipulation that you want.